# How to store Google Map Circle data in MySql Database

Tags: mysql, laravel, geometry, coordinates, center

I am trying to store Google Map Circle data in MySql Database. I choose `text` data type to store Center Coordinate and `int` to store radius of the center. Now I am using below code to fetch data from those column.

```
$zone = RestaurantZones::whereRaw( "ST_Distance(circle_coordinates, ?) <= radius", [$point] )->pluck( 'id' );
```

I am getting below error.

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[22023]: Invalid parameter value: 3037 Invalid GIS data provided to function st_distance.
```

How can I store Google Map Circle data in MySql Database ?

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty clear from the error shown, to store and retrieve this kind of data, you should use MySQL's spatial data types and functions.

"(Just for revision) Imagine you have a map with circles on it, like the Google Map circles. Each circle has a center (the middle point) and a radius (how big it is).

- When you want to save this information in a computer, you can't just use regular numbers. You need a special way, like using a special code for these circles. In computer language, this is called "spatial data.
- In this table, you tell the computer that one column is for the center of the circle, and another column is for the radius.

**Having a table that uses spatial data types**

```
CREATE TABLE restaurant_zones (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    circle_coordinates POINT, -- for storing the center coordinates
    radius INT,
    SPATIAL INDEX(circle_coordinates) -- create a spatial index for better performance
);
```

- Use MySQL's `ST_GeomFromText` function to create a point from the center coordinates.

```
INSERT INTO restaurant_zones (circle_coordinates, radius) VALUES (ST_GeomFromText('POINT(11.1111.111)', 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your **circle_coordinates** column in the **RestaurantZones** table is defined as a spatial data type into your Model.
if you are using this package

> grimzy/laravel-mysql-spatial

then model should looks like this.

```
use Grimzy\LaravelMysqlSpatial\Eloquent\SpatialTrait;

    class RestaurantZones extends Model
    {
        use SpatialTrait;
    
        protected $fillable = ['name', 'coordinates', 'radius'];
    
        protected $spatialFields = [
            'coordinates',
        ];
    }
```

In your migration field type should be in the point

```
$table->point('circle_coordinates');
```

And

```
use Grimzy\LaravelMysqlSpatial\Types\Point;

$point = new Point($latitude, $longitude);
```

If you've ensured that the **circle_coordinates** and **radius** columns are correctly defined, and you're passing a valid Point object for the **$point** variable, you should be able to use **ST_Distance** without encountering the "Invalid GIS data" error. If the issue persists, you may want to check the actual data in your database to make sure there are no anomalies or inconsistencies in the spatial data.